# How to move objects in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can objects be moved with tikz in beamer - like in this [video](https://youtu.be/xQ3sNEIHAAQ?t=495)?
(For non german speaking persons: the speaker says that the example at 8:15 is made with beamer and tkiz)

Comment: Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=en ? (never tried it. Seems nice)

Comment: You could use the built-in animations in `tikz` see section *26.2 Creating an animation*